# Only DATE in DATETIME column in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

Good day, I am doing an application in C# and I connect to a Mysql database. I have a column that is of type datetime and doing the select from the application also sends me the time. Only I am interested in the date.

```
MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand();
            comando.Connection = conexion;
            comando.CommandText = "SELECT codgrupo,fecha,ciudad FROM actuacion";
            MySqlDataReader DR = comando.ExecuteReader();
            while (DR.Read())
            {
                ListViewItem ITEM = lvact.Items.Add(DR["codGrupo"].ToString());
                ITEM.SubItems.Add(DR["fecha"].ToString());
                ITEM.SubItems.Add(DR["ciudad"].ToString());
            }
            DR.Close();
            conexion.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the date part of a C# DateTime variable by its Date property:

```
var myDateOnly = myDateTime.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT DATE(YourDate)
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Does not work, since the inquiry has more fields, I believe that I have to do when using the DataReader to filter, but not is fine as it is.

Comment: which column is date ?

Comment: fecha is the date column.

Comment: than, use this: `SELECT codgrupo,date(fecha) as 'fecha',ciudad FROM actuacion`

Comment: I've tried it but time keeps passing me

Comment: Answers should be more detailed and have good explanation of the solution. Avoid answers that is nothing but just a code-snippet. Please elaborate your answer.